# How do I download two files from a website and save as two different names using linux?

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download TCGA-LUAD manifest and TSV file from

https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/repository?facetTab=files&files_size=10&filters=%7B%22content%22%3A%5B%7B%22content%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22cases.project.project_id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%22TCGA-LUAD%22%5D%7D%2C%22op%22%3A%22in%22%7D%2C%7B%22content%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22files.experimental_strategy%22%2C%22value%22%3A%5B%22Diagnostic%20Slide%22%5D%7D%2C%22op%22%3A%22in%22%7D%5D%2C%22op%22%3A%22and%22%7D&searchTableTab=files

and save as “… TCGA_LUAD.txt TCGA_LUAD.tsv”

Can I use something like:
wget -O fileA|fileB weblink.com
?

Answer (score 0):

1. To download file and rename it use command :
   -> wget https://example.com/example.csv -O myfilename.txt
2. To combine multiple downloads you use && , as | operator will pass the output from first execution to another which will not be useful in this case so maybe you use something like :
   -> wget https://example.com/example.csv -O myfilename.txt && wget https://example.com/example2.csv -O myfilename2.txt